# Interpretation of interactions in inverse gamma glmm

Tags: r, interpretation, glmmtmb, inverse-gamma-distribution

i want to calculate the effects that the interaction between zone (4 levels), species (2 levels) and distance from contact zone (continuous) has on the pulse repetition period - song rate of the two species of birds. The model is:

```
PRP ~ zone * species.no * mindist + (1 | Location/Bird_ID),family = Gamma(inverse)
```

The output is the following:

```
Family: Gamma  ( inverse )
Formula:          PRP ~ zone * species.no * mindist + (1 | Location/Bird_ID)
Data: contact

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -2577.8  -2491.6   1307.9  -2615.8      671 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Bird_ID:Location (Intercept) 0.007613 0.08726 
 Location         (Intercept) 0.001765 0.04201 
Number of obs: 690, groups:  Bird_ID:Location, 627; Location, 164

Dispersion estimate for Gamma family (sigma^2): 0.00156 

Conditional model:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                1.433220   0.030473   47.03  < 2e-16 ***
zone2                      0.310226   0.041601    7.46 8.84e-14 ***
zone3                      0.283021   0.039258    7.21 5.63e-13 ***
zone4                     -0.050648   0.048638   -1.04   0.2977    
species.no2                0.435872   0.044699    9.75  < 2e-16 ***
mindist                   -0.014873   0.012338   -1.21   0.2280    
zone2:species.no2         -0.483068   0.069137   -6.99 2.81e-12 ***
zone3:species.no2         -0.245453   0.049792   -4.93 8.24e-07 ***
zone4:species.no2         -0.102174   0.064175   -1.59   0.1114    
zone2:mindist              0.002603   0.019550    0.13   0.8941    
zone3:mindist              0.010169   0.018732    0.54   0.5872    
zone4:mindist             -0.011446   0.031609   -0.36   0.7173    
species.no2:mindist        0.032881   0.022442    1.47   0.1429    
zone2:species.no2:mindist  0.059971   0.036319    1.65   0.0987 .  
zone3:species.no2:mindist  0.070591   0.027489    2.57   0.0102 *  
zone4:species.no2:mindist  0.031448   0.044048    0.71   0.4753
```

My question is how should i interpret the interaction term results? For example, what is the two way significant term zone2:species.no2 compared with? zone2: species.no1 or zone1:species.no1. Also, are the p-values for the higher order effects are affected by the lower order effect P values?

Thank you in advance!